# Data recovery from deleted operating system

Tags: linux, data-recovery

recently i have installed Windows 7 on my laptop. i was using ubuntu. i had some important documents in ubuntu.  i forgot to take back up of that documents and i formatted my laptop and recreated new partitions.

now i am trying to recover the deleted documents from my hard drive but don't know how can i get my files recovered?

is there any free software that help me to recover my deleted data?

i did  try Ease us Data recovery but it doesn't show anything.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on how large your disk is. Recovering from formatting is fairly simple - if done immediately. Now that you have overwritten parts of your disk with many gB of MS Windows, your chances lessen. The smaller the disk, the harder it will be.  I have had some success with http://www.minitool-partitionrecovery.com/ but YMMV.

Comment: BTW, it should go without saying, but STOP using that drive right now!! Whatever you do, don't run Windows from it. Don't do anything with it. Take it out & put it in an external case and try to recover from that using another PC.

Answer (score 5):

As already pointed out in the comments on the question itself, having the drive already re-partitioned and installed several GiBs have lessened your chances drastically – but there might still be a chance, at least for parts of the data. First, let me repeat Mawg's advice to not use the drive until your recovery is done, specifically don't boot from it – or your chances will get even smaller.

Try recovering data while booted from a different disk – a Live-CD is best fitted for that. I've had good experiences with **[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)** in the past: it is available cross-platform, and knows a lot of file systems and data types. They even have such a [TestDisk LiveCD](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd) available which you could use for that, so no installation required.

For alternatives, you might wish to take a look at the [data-recovery tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) of our sister-site Android.SE, which offers useful links. Good luck!